# Using self-defined criterion in stepwise regression in r

Tags: r

I want to perform a stepwise logistic regression, but I would like to define my own criterion instead of using the standard criteria such as 'p-values', 'AIC', etc.

I tried using the step function in R but the `test` parameter only allows predefined values(chisquare, F, etc.). Is there any other function available that allows you to define your own criterion? If not, I have no idea how to code this myself.

Comment: You will have to cade it yourself. Not difficult

Comment: I've been trying to code it myself, but I am stuck at trying to loop through all possible feature subsets of the full model. Any suggestions? It cannot be done manually since I have 82 variables.